# How to go about solving $\int \frac{\cos^4(x)}{\sin^7(x)} dx$

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{\cos^4(x)}{\sin^7(x)} dx$

I don't see any viable trig properties to utilize immediately.

Do I just proceed with integration by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Set $\cos x=u$ in $$\int\dfrac{\cos^4x}{\sin^8x}\sin x\ dx$$

More generally for $$\int\cos^mx\sin^{2n+1}x\ dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\cot^4x\csc^3x\ dx=\int(\csc^2x-1)^2\csc^3x\ dx=\int(I_7-2I_5+I_3)dx$$

where $I_n=\int\csc^nx\ dx$

Now use [this](http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction_5.html).